# Can you run a 15 amp light circuit off of a 20 amp outlet

Tags: electrical, light-fixture

Need an extra light in the garage, but separately switched. Any reason why I couldn't add a pigtail from the outlet and connect the light and switch with 14 gauge using an inline 15 amp fuse inside the box? The led bulb probably wouldn't use more than 1 amp. It seems like a silly application of code that it requires a separate 15 amp service considering the alternative is simply plug the exact same light into the outlet.

Comment: You could just use 12 guage wire. I believe that we recently had a question which clarified that a 15A switch was fine if it was switching lights, not receptacles, on a 20A circuit. I don't think "an inline fuse" is going to fly from a "listed and approved for the application" point of view, though you could probably find a fuseholder that would work, but it won't take much part cost to exceed the cost differential of 12ga .vs. 14 ga wire/cable. https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/207542/18078

Comment: Why are you opposed to using 12AWG wiring for the lighting run?

Comment: I'm not, except that the extra 6' of 12 gauge would mean buying another 100' and having 94' left over. I'm more interested in what possible scenario would be unsafe. Aside from someone screwing in a 2,000 watt bulb, the bulb itself is a fuse.

Comment: Or you could go to a better store that'll sell you #12 by the foot.

Comment: The risky aspect might be a high resistance fault to ground on that 14ga part of the circuit and the 20A breaker takes too long to react to it, allowing a fire to start inside of the walls or ceiling. If you put in a receptacle on the 20A circuit and plugged in the fixture, the cord on the fixture is exposed and visible, so less risk of a fault going unnoticed. Now, if it were a 20A AFCI breaker, then that risk might be ameliorated...